# How do I declare the version number for a Perl module?

Tags: perl, syntax, coding-style

I thought I knew how to declare version numbers for modules. But after reading the article "$VERSION Confusion" at [Modern Perl Books, a Modern Perl Blog](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/07/version-confusion.html); I'm now more confused than I started. (Ignorance was indeed bliss.) Not that I have hangups about "perfect" code but I'm just really curious why such a trivial matter apparently has no definitive answer for such a mature language.

Hope the SO community can find a definitive answer to this question as there are better things for Perl hackers to do than argue about different ways to declare version numbers.

Comment: "I'm just really curious why such a trivial matter apparently has no definitive answer for such a mature language". There is more than one way to do it (tm)  ;-) ;-(

Comment: Excellent answers everyone. @Thilo, more than one way indeed.

Comment: Versions in Perl are a loong, painful story. David Golden has written a series of blog posts about them that tell much of the whole story. It's *really not* a simple matter even though it may seem so. (You know, like Fermat's last theorem ;) As a result of David's thinking and a lot of discussion on the perl5-porters list, we believe to have worked out a reasonable way forward without breaking backwards compatibility. Search the p5p archives for details.

Comment: http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/369/version-numbers-should-be-boring/

Comment: @daxim Cool article. Never knew (or bothered) about the story behind it. Version numbers should be boring.

Comment: This is Perl all over, most of it is a dog's breakfast and you spend more time working on trivial issues like this than should be necessary. They cover it up by saying "There is more than one way to do it (tm)" as if that is a good thing. I would much rather be spending my time adding a useful feature than wasting my time reading an article about the history of versioning in Perl (one where I'm sure they made plenty of mistakes, changed their minds multiple times and written a module to compensate for those mistakes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> #### [`use Module VERSION`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)
>
> If the VERSION argument is present between Module and LIST, then the `use` will call the `VERSION` method in class `Module` with the given version as an argument. The default `VERSION` method, inherited from the `UNIVERSAL` class, croaks if the given version is larger than the value of the variable `$Module::VERSION`.

That makes for a straightforward pattern:

```
package MyModule;

our $VERSION = 1.23;

# ...

1;
```

Comment: I've been using 'our' since it was introduced.

Answer (score 10):

My position is *keep it simple*.  **Declare your version as a string containing a floating point number.**  Leave the multiple-decimal stuff for Perl's version numbers and Perl 6.

If your module requires Perl 5.6.0 or later:

```
our $VERSION = '1.02';
```

Or, if you need to remain compatible with Perl 5.005 or older:

```
use vars '$VERSION';
$VERSION = '1.02';
```

Some additional points:

1. **Always use the same number of digits after the decimal point.**  Some (non-Perl) packaging tools think version 1.11 comes after 1.9 but before 1.90.  If you need to change the number of digits you use, increment the major version number at the same time.
2. **Always declare the version as a string.**  This keeps trailing zeros from disappearing.  (See point 1.)
3. If you want to make an unstable (e.g. alpha or beta) release, append the string `-TRIAL` to the *distribution's* version number (e.g. upload `Foo-Bar-1.90-TRIAL.tar.gz` containing Foo::Bar 1.90).  This tells CPAN to list it as a development release, just as if it contained an underscore.  [Dist::Zilla](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dist::Zilla) makes it easy to make trial releases.

A string containing a floating point number will work with all versions of Perl, all versions of MakeMaker & Module::Build, and all Linux distributions I'm aware of.

Comment: Note: If you're currently using multiple-decimal versions, **do not** switch to a floating point version unless you increment the major version number at the same time (e.g., it's safe to go from 4.3.2 to '5.00', but not to '4.40').

Comment: Correction: pretty much everything in the world besides Perl thinks that 1.11 comes after 1.9 :)

Comment: @hobbs: Sure? write a program like: `1.11 > 1.9 ? print "YES" : print "NO"`

Answer (score 8):

Most of your confusion is, I suspect, due to the page you linked advocating 1.2.3 style version "numbers".  These are not fully supported throughout all the toolchain (regardless of what others may say) and should not be used.  They offer no advantage over a simple numeric version, since they must for compatibility be treated as just a number in many places (e.g. 1.2.3 is treated as 1.002003).

The correct way to declare a version number is simple, unless you have an XS component or a alpha/beta indicator (_ in the version number), since then some things need to see a version string and some things a version number.  Then it gets more complicated.  [perlmodstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodstyle.html) provides the correct incantation:

> If you want to release a 'beta' or
>   'alpha' version of a module but don't
>   want CPAN.pm to list it as most recent
>   use an '_' after the regular version
>   number followed by at least 2 digits,
>   eg. 1.20_01. If you do this, the
>   following idiom is recommended:
>
> ```
> $VERSION = "1.12_01";
> $XS_VERSION = $VERSION; # only needed if you have XS code
> $VERSION = eval $VERSION;
> ```

(This assumes $VERSION and $XS_VERSION have already been declared; if not, simply add `our` to the first two lines.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the eval idiom. You may want to leave this in all the time, so you don't forget to put it in when it's needed.

Comment: Another way to handle alpha versions is to append the string `-TRIAL` to the _distribution's_ version number (not the module).  e.g., CPAN will list `Foo-Bar-1.90-TRIAL.tar.gz` (containing Foo::Bar 1.90) as a development release, just as if it contained an underscore.  Dist::Zilla makes it easy to make such a trial release.

Answer (score 0):

The standard for perl version is described in the module [version](https://metacpan.org/pod/version) and there are two types:

1. dotted decimal style like the one used by perl itself, i.e. v5.8.32
   or just 5.8.32; or
2. decimal style such as 1.0203

In dotted-decimal style, which is the recommended style, the three digits represent respectively major, minor and patch. More on this here on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning)

Alpha versions are marked with digits separated from the rest by an underscore, such as: 5.8.32_01

The requirements advocated by perl are:

1. "Always use a dotted-decimal with (at least) three components"
2. "Always use a leading-v"
3. "Always quote the version"

Thus, when declaring a version in a perl module, one would simply use something like:

```
package MyModule;
BEGIN
{
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    our $VERSION = 'v1.2.3';
};

# some code here
1;

__END__
```

When using a module, as per [the perl documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#use-Module-VERSION-LIST), one would write:

```
use Module 12.34;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->VERSION(12.34) }
```